# Python raw_input messing up string concatenation

Tags: python, windows, string, concatenation, raw-input

I am trying to do something relatively simple in Python and am surprised at how badly this isn't working for how simple it should be.

I'm here just trying to concatenate three simple strings.  The input typed at raw_input is `"abc"` in all cases below:

```
proj = raw_input("Name of project: ")
print proj
ProjRegex = 'test1' + proj + 'test2'
print ProjRegex
```

Yields:

```
abc
test2abc
```

Case 2

```
proj = raw_input("Name of project: ")
print proj
ProjRegex = 'test1%stest2' % (proj)
print ProjRegex
```

Yields:

```
abc
test2abc
```

Note that in both cases instead of printing `"test1abctest2"`, as expected, it's substituting test2 for test1.

Then I noticed that if instead of using raw_input at all, if I say:

```
proj = "abc"
ProjRegex = 'test1' + proj + 'test2'
```

Then it behaves as expected.

So is something happening in `raw_input()` that is wanting to do string substitution?  My understanding is it takes keyboard input, strips a newline, and returns as a string.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got the output you see, but that's not the output you get when you run this code as a Python script. I see `"test1abctest2"` just fine. It is as if something added `\r` carriage returns.

Comment: I bet that if you added `print repr(proj)` you'll see the input is  `abc\r` instead.

Comment: If this was happening because you are on windows, you should re-tag the question appropriately.

Comment: For the record: The OP explained the problem well, provided input and expected output, and has a genuine question. I don't see why this deserved to be downvoted this much.

Comment: @ansh01:  I tested this on Windows.  I am not getting the same output.

Comment: @ansh0l: This does not necessarily have to be on Windows. And *normally*, I'd expect `sys.stdin` to be opened in text mode and Python will *translate* `\r\n` Windows line endings for you, and `raw_input()` will not normally return carriage returns in the result.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Exactly, this is a deeper problem. `sys.stdin` does not appear to be opened in text mode here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My comment was only a suggestion after reading the answers and seeing the number of downvotes so as to save the OP from further downvotes in case this was a windows specific issue.

Comment: @ansh0l: I very much doubt the downvoters were voting on the basis of a missing flag..

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Any speculations on how `sys.stdin` ended up not being entered in text mode?  Where should the OP start looking?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I'd need to go spelunking for the ins and outs of how CPython handles this, something I won't start doing until the OP has given us more details; specifically what interpreter, what version, and what shell or console is being used here.

Comment: Hi all, wow thanks for the many responses.  Yes, I am programming in Windows (for the first time, Python+Windows).  I forgot that Windows handles newline characters differently than in Linux, which I'm accustomed to.  Give me a minute to look more into the responses, but I'm guessing that must be the answer.

Comment: Would you happen to have replaced `sys.stdin`?

Comment: I don't suppose you're running the script by doing `python -u myscript.py`?

Comment: @Kevin:  I think you've got it.  [Docs on `python -u`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u): "Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. On systems where it matters, also **put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode**."  It's also possible that [`PYTHONUNBUFFERED`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) has been set "If this is set to a non-empty string it is equivalent to specifying the -u option."

Comment: That is it, I am calling python -u to use my script as a plugin to another tool.  What does being unbuffered, or binary mode, mean in relation to the \r vs \n?

Comment: @while1:  In text mode, Python translates platform specific line endings to `'\n'`.  In windows the line endings are `'\r\n'`.  `raw_input` reads until it encounters an `'\n'` and returns the previous characters, minus the newline.  In your example, it turns `'abc\r\n'` to `'abc\r'`.  `raw_input` doesn't strip the `'\r'` because it is not expecting `stdin` to be in binary mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This must be a problem related to a a trailing `\r`...
Try this:

```
'test1' + proj.rstrip() + 'test2'
```

Explanation:

Your concatenated string contains `\r` in the middle. When printed, the console *does* print the beginning as `test1...` but when it encounters the `\r`, it ["carriage-returns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) to the beginning of the line, and overwrites it with the rest.

[Further reading about newlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations)

Comment: Python opens `sys.stdin` in text mode, meaning that newline conventions are automatically translated to `\n`. The `\r` here is *not normal*.

Comment: I think you are correct that this is being caused by having a trailing `'\r'`.  However, I'm not sure how he is ending up with the `'\r'` at the end of the string.  He still needs to figure that out.  It's probably in code that was not presented.

Comment: Yes, the output of print proj and print repr(proj), respectively, is abc
'abc\r'
I am using Python2.7, running in cmd.exe on Windows7.  So, indeed, \r is getting put in the middle of the string, as shx2 explained well.  There is no other code that I have left out.  

Indeed, using proj.rstrip() worked, thank you!

I am still not sure why the \r is not getting translated to \n.  As far as I am concerned, I am happy.  Thank you all.

Comment: I am happy to provide the info required to answer the new question, why is my sys.stdin not working as expected.  I am just using the default Python2.7 install, as far as I know I'm not replacing the sys.stdin call.  How would I even check?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You're running under Windows, correct? The string you enter is terminated by a DOS line ending, so that `ProjRegex` consists of `test1abc\rtest2`. When printed, the `\r` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, at which point `test2` overwrites `test1`.

Comment: Ditto here: Python opens `sys.stdin` in text mode, meaning that newline conventions are automatically translated to `\n`. The `\r` here is *not normal*.

Comment: Yes, I thought Python should be handling that automatically. I agree that how the `\r` showed up is a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify if you've set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable? When set on Windows, you will definitely run into issues where raw_input returns the `\r`. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).