# Why does raw_input() take "enter" as a character to the users input

Tags: python, raw-input

I'm using notepad++ and run with Python 2.7. If I'm running the code below and enter the word "nice" the `len()` function returns 5 instead of four. As far as I could find out the fifth letter is the "enter" I need to press to confirm my input "nice". What is wrong?

```
userchoice = raw_input("Please type in nice:")
userchoice=str(userchoice)
print len(userchoice)
if userchoice == 'nice':
    print "YESSSS"
else:
    print "Didn't work"
```

Comment: Unable to replicate: `Please type in nice:nice
4
YESSSS`

Comment: Try stripping it with userchoice.strip()

Comment: Also unable to reproduce

Comment: @Andy Try on MS-DOS(CMD), there the newline character is `\r\n`, and that is going to leave behind a `\r`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I am still unable to reproduce this on Windows 7 Python 2.7.5, I don't think this should be happening.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Others have surely faced this issue before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358655/python-raw-input-messing-up-string-concatenation#comment30392805_20358715 and https://bugs.python.org/issue11272(Python 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly do `userchoice.strip()` to remove the newline.

Moreover, there's no need to do `str(userchoice)` since `raw_input returns a string already.

Comment: Thank you. .strip() helped. The str(userchoice) is a leftover from my experiments. Thank you Ashwini. That's the reason!

Comment: @ChristianMai, you should check the question your question (lol, how to rephrase it? :)) is a duplicate of, there is an explanation.